# How to save a sparse dataset to be used by scikit-learn?

Tags: java, python, scikit-learn

I'm writing a java text mining tool. I want to test my dataset with `scikit-learn` classifiers. I'm creating the feature vectors on the fly with Java and the vectors are very sparse. I want to export my sparse vectors/dataset into a format that can be usable with `scikit-learn` easily. I already wrote an export function in Java to export the dataset in an ARFF format, but I found that there is no way to read that with `scikit-learn`. There are some python parsers for ARFF files but they don't support sparse datasets.

So how to export my dataset to a format usable with `scikit-learn`? i.e which format?!

Answer (score 0):

A sub-optimal but simple approach is to use the libsvm / svmlight format which is a plain text format using

label feature_index:feature_value feature_index:feature_value

This can work fine if you data is not too large.
You can read it with sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file.

I'm a bit surprised arff readers in python don't support sparse data. Have you tried [scipy.io.arff.loadarff](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.io.arff.loadarff.html) ?

Comment: No support for sparse arff format. I think there is a pull request for this though.

Comment: My arff file is about 100MB, so is that considered large? Note that this arff only contains the non-zero information.

Comment: No, you should be fine. It will probably not load instantaneously but it will be ok.